# Why does it feel warmer when it is snowing?

Tags: temperature, humidity

It doesn't snow a lot where I live, but whenever it does and I go outside, the air feels warmer than I would expect on an clear day with an equivalent temperature, even though thermometer on my car reads -1 C° which is colder than most clear days. Does this have anything to do with humidity?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about human perception of temperature, not physics.

Comment: I request reopening. The question asks why it feels warmer in the snow and then asks a follow-up - does it have anything to do with humidity? These are two separate questions, and I will attempt to explain that humidity may or may not be part of the answer.

Comment: I edited your question, changing "in the snow" to "when it is snowing", which is opposed to a "clear day". I hope this is what you intended, and it may allow the question to be reopened.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast It sounds to me like you should simply write an answer to the question that this one is (marked) a duplicate of, which *also* asks: Does humidity make [winter] air feel colder? It seems to me like your comment does not demonstrate that this post is actually asking something different.

Comment: @Danu - I suggest that humidity is potentially irrelevant. It's the difference between overcast and clear that I would like to address.